# Edititemtemplate not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to display a editable textbox in gridview, but the textbox is not visible.

Thank you all for answers.

But the problem is still same,

EDITED CODE:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ele_display_grid" runat="server" CssClass="stream_elements_grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="ele_display_grid_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="ele_display_grid_RowUpdating">
 <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Element Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="new_grid_ele" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("element_name") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Composition">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="new_grid_compo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("composition") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

In code behind:

```
protected void get_selected_vals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }

 private void BindGrid()
    {
        List<ListItem> selected = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (ListItem item in ajaxElementsCheckbox.Items)
            if (item.Selected) selected.Add(item);

        for (int i = 0; i < selected.Count; i++)
        {
            string name = selected[i].ToString();
            double compo = 1;

            stream_list my_str = new stream_list(name, compo);
            elenamescompolist.Add(my_str);

        }//end of outer for.

        ele_display_grid.DataSource = elenamescompolist;
        ele_display_grid.DataBind();
    }

  protected void ele_display_grid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("On row Editing.......");
    }

    protected void ele_display_grid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("On row updating.......");
    }
```

I am getting edit link but I cant click it..

EDITTING:

It is solved... I was placing the gridview over an image, problem was with the z-index. I changed the z-index of background image to 0 and it all worked.. Thank to all for answers..

Comment: TextBox is in `EditItemTemplate`, which means it won't be visible unless grid row is in edit mode. Is this how you want it to work?

Comment: @Andrei: I tried putting it in <itemtemplate> it was visible but not editable. I want it to be visible when gridview is loaded but it has to be editable. Is it possible..

Comment: @user2186239. You can check the textbox in the `ItemTemplate` but as soon as you will refresh the page or postback occur, change will be gone.

Comment: What are the DataKeys for this GridView?

Comment: @user1914368: Sorry i dint get it.... what are DataKeys..

Answer (score 1):

As you specified TextBox to be shown in the edit mode. It will not be display unless your gridview edit index equal to specific row index.

Look at detail at [GridView.EditIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Normally `asp:CommandField` can be added in GridView Markup:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" 
                  HeaderText="Edit/Update" 
                  ShowEditButton="True"
                  ShowHeader="True">                                
</asp:CommandField>
```

You need to track these events

```
OnRowEditing  //for settings GridView.EditIndex to GridViewRow Index
OnRowCancelingEdit //for setting GridView.EditIndex back to -1
OnRowUpdating //for updating record and setting GridView.EditIndex back to -1
```

**UPDATE**:

First of all of keep datasource binding into a separate method:

```
protected void get_selected_vals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
       BindGrid();
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    List<ListItem> selected = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (ListItem item in ajaxElementsCheckbox.Items)
        if (item.Selected) selected.Add(item);

    for(int i=0; i<selected.Count; i++)
    {            
        string name = selected[i].ToString();
        double compo = 1;

        stream_list my_str = new stream_list(name, compo);
        elenamescompolist.Add(my_str);


    }//end of outer for.

   ele_display_grid.DataSource = elenamescompolist;
   ele_display_grid.DataBind();
}
```

**Row Editing Event of GridView**:

```
 protected void ele_display_grid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {            
        ele_display_grid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }
```

**Row Updating Event of GridView**:

```
 protected void ele_display_grid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Update datasource here

        ele_display_grid.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }
```

**Row Canceling Edit Event of GridView**:

```
protected void ele_display_grid_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        ele_display_grid.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }
```

Comment: I am getting your point. I have added commandfield and have added OnRowEditing for gridview, but not able to click the link nothing is happening...